# Best practice (most secure) User role storage in MERN web app

Tags: reactjs, authentication, jwt, mern, redux-toolkit

I'm working on a MERN stack User Authentication template using the best practices I can possibly find in terms of security and efficiency, however, I'm having a hard time figuring out where best to store User roles ('administrator', etc.) which I'm using to determine what content to render in my React components.

I've noticed many resources state to simply put the User role along with other non-private data into localStorage or Session storage, however, since I'm using this data to determine what to render in the components, someone could easily change the values in localStorage or session storage, getting the components to render administrator content for standard user.

My routes are protected and so the actions wouldn't work despite being rendered, but I still don't want non-administrators to be able to change a local variable and have visibility.

**My Initial Idea:**

I'm returning an ***Access*** token (15 second expiration) within 'Authorization' header from my server to be stored in localStorage on the front-end upon registration, login, and token refresh, to make authenticated requests. I'm also returning a ***Refresh*** token (24 hour expiration) via http-only cookie during registration, login, and token refresh to refresh both Access and Refresh tokens when the Access token expires, and they both contain the user data as a payload.

I was thinking to set my User slice state on every refresh by verifying the Access token in localStorage and using the payload data returned, this way I know the data in the User slice state is authentic. The problem with that is that the Access token expires every 15 seconds so I would need to use hit my refreshTokens route to get new tokens each time I want to update my user state as well. This strikes me as very inefficient and un-scalable. Having many users hitting the refreshTokens endpoint every 15 seconds simply to update their client-side state doesn't seem right.

**Potential Solution:**

I could make a third JWT to store the same (user) data which would expire in the same time as the refresh token which would mean both my user state and user authentication would expire simultaneously, requiring the user to re-authenticate as normal. Though, I would need to generate and pass the third token with the other tokens to keep their expirations in line. Not even sure if this is the best solution - probably not. Maybe I should be handling the state differently; not updating it with each refresh?

... As I'm writing this - I'm wondering if, despite expiring, I could still read the Access token in localStorage to update the User state using a 'decode' method. I will be looking into this more after posting, as I'm still curious to hear what others think.

EDIT: I don't think 'decoded' will work, considering it simply decodes *a* JWT which could be any JWT. It doesn't verify or validate it with my secret, therefore someone could change the localstorage to be a valid JWT with a payload of their choosing which would be falsely decoded into the user state.

Any thoughts on how best to store the User role / User data so that I can access it efficiently upon each refresh would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I solved this ultimately my introducing a third JWT (userToken) which I made expire in the same time as my refreshToken to coincide the user data being valid until the refreshToken (authentication period) expires.

They are also refreshed together so they always have the same expiration times - the refreshToken, however, is securely stored in the HTTP-only cookie and used to authenticate on the back-end while the userToken is stored in the local storage and is used to set the state on the front-end while the accessToken is used to verify both.

This just doesn't sound extremely convenient or optimal so I'm sure it's not, but I will be looking at ways to improve this approach moving forward.